# I need grouping separator for my number but dont want the added formatting of NumberFormatter, Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, textfield

I need grouping separator for my number but don't want the added formatting of NumberFormatter, Swift 3
i have this:

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.decimal
let digits = NSNumber(value: Float(sender.text!)!)
sender.text = numberFormatter.string(from: digits)!
```

All I want is the comma grouping!
i would appreciate any help.

Comment: What other formatting do you not want? What is your number and what do you want it to look like? And what does it currently look like?

Comment: for example: 0.500 should not be changed to 0.5 and 0.0 should be 0.0. Thanks. Okay i am working on a calculator with 2 textfields, and i want users to click on each and edit it and then it adds the grouping as it changes but not to prevent the user from typing 0.5001